# Falling factorials $[x]_0,[x]_1\ldots [x]_n$ form a basis for vector space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Here is a lemma which requires the use of falling factorials which are written as $[x]_n=x(x-1)\ldots(x-(n-1))$ :

> **Lemma**:Let $V$ be a vector space of polynomials over $\mathbb C$ , then $[x]_0,[x]_1\ldots [x]_n$ is a basis for $V$.
>
> **Proof**: for degree $0$: $c[x]_0=P(x)$
>
> Assume it is true for degree $n-1$.Now,
>   $P(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots +a_nx^n$,$a_n \neq 0$.
>
> $Q(x)=P(x)-a_n[x]_n$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n-1$
>
> by induction $Q(x)=b_0[x]_0+b_1[x]_1+\ldots+b_{\text{n-1}}[x]_{\text{n-1}}.$
>   $\therefore P(x)=b_0[x]_0+b_1[x]_1+\ldots+b_{\text{n-1}}[x]_{\text{n-1}}+a_n[x]_n.$
>
> thus, $[x]_0,\ldots ,[x]_n$ is a generating set.
>
> $\lambda_0[x]_0+\lambda_1[x]_1+\ldots \lambda_n[x]_n \cong 0$
>
> comparing coefficients of $x^n$ we get:
>                        $\lambda_n=0$
>
> Now,$\lambda_0[x]_0+\lambda_1[x]_1+\ldots \lambda_{\text{n-1}}[x]_{\text{n-1}} \cong 0$
>
> comparing coefficients of $x^{\text{n-1}}$ we get   $\lambda_{\text{n-1}}=0$ and going on like this we get,
>
> $\lambda_0=\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\ldots=\lambda_n=0$
>
> $\implies$ $[x]_0,\ldots ,[x]_n$ are linearly independent.
>   $\implies$ they form basis.

Here I can't understand things like:

- How can we write $Q(x)=P(x)-a_n[x]_n$?
- How did we conclude: $\lambda_0=\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\ldots=\lambda_n=0$ 
  and not some non-zero value by just comparing coeffiecients of respective degrees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. We can write $Q(x)=P(x)-a_n[x]_n$ because that's a definition for $Q(x)$.  The author of the proof can define this however she or he wants.
2. The polynomial $\lambda_0[x]_0+\cdots+\lambda_n[x]_n$ is of degree $n$, and the coefficient of $x^n$ is $\lambda_n$.  However the polynomial is the zero polynomial, so we must have $\lambda_n=0$.  Now look at the next smaller coefficient, and so on.

Comment: ok I got it...thanks